# Create custom page for lock

Tags: linux, shell, dnsmasq, hosts, dd-wrt

I'm new to `DD-WRT v3.0-r39469 std (04/10/19)` so I have several questions!

I want to make a custom `LOCKING PAGE` in the domain `127.0.0.2` in my network, is it possible?

I ran the page to which I wanted the router to make a "virtual host" at `127.0.0.2`

```
http://vinibudd.dx.am/rot-site-locked.html
```

My code

```
echo '127.0.0.2 http://vinibudd.dx.am/rot-site-bloqueado.html' >> /tmp/hosts
killall -HUP dnsmasq
stopservice dnsmasq && startservice dnsmasq
```

So when I was blocking a site I would

```
address=/exemple.com/127.0.0.2
```

... and redirect